# vuetify - background showing between main and footer

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify project. On any iphone that is using iOS 10.whatever, there is a gap between my main section and footer where only the background is displayed.

I have done everything I can think of and it this point it's probably something I'm easily overlooking, but it seems as tho the v-content is not taking up the entire main section. Anyone run into this issue before?

```
<template>
<v-app style="background-color: rgba(238,232,205,1);">
    <app-age-verification></app-age-verification>
    <main>
        <v-content>
            <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                <router-view>
                    <v-container fluid></v-container>
                </router-view>
            </transition>
        </v-content>
    </main>
  <app-footer app></app-footer>
</v-app>
</template>
```

Component example:

```
<template>
<section id="main">
    <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs6 sm4>
                <img :src="home.logo">
                <br><br>
                <v-layout justify-center wrap>
                  <v-btn style="background-color: #661e26; 
                               color: #eee8cd"
                           large
                           @click="auth">
                        {{ b1 }}
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn style="background-color: #661e26; 
                                  color: #eee8cd"
                           large
                           @click="navigateToCustomer">
                        {{ b2 }}
                    </v-btn>
                </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</section>
</template>
```

Thank you

Comment: What version of vuetify are you using?

Comment: "vuetify": "^0.16.3"

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the `<main>` tags. I had a similar issue with one of my layouts.

```
<template>
 <v-app style="background-color: rgba(238,232,205,1);">
  <app-age-verification></app-age-verification>
    <v-content>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <router-view>
                <v-container fluid></v-container>
            </router-view>
        </transition>
    </v-content>
  <app-footer app></app-footer>
 </v-app>
</template>
```

The `<main>` tag will soon be deprecated, here is the [github issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/2298). Although it seems to be impacting things before the 0.17.x release.

Comment: After I removed the main tag it applied that gap to all machines.

Comment: Hmm. Could you post the code for your custom components?

Comment: Added above. Thank you